# What does a CMOS chip look like?

Tags: bios, cmos

I'm trying to figure out the difference between BIOS and CMOS.

I always thought the BIOS setup was software installed onto the CMOS chip. According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKaKj6uRLSM) video, the BIOS and CMOS are both chips. But the video only shows the CMOS battery, the jumper and the BIOS chip (looks like an IC). None of the tutorials/articles explain to me what the CMOS chip looks like. So what does it look like? Is it even tangible?

P.S. "The CMOS chip stores the settings of the BIOS setup, whereas the BIOS chip stores the BIOS setup program." Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The CMOS" is a small memory where the BIOS can store settings - it's the same device as the clock.

On the original 5150 IBM PC introduced in 1981, it did not have a CMOS - BIOS settings were controlled by DIP switches on the motherboard.

The IBM PC AT that came out afterward included a Motorola MC146818 real-time clock - the clock was battery backed and included a 64-byte memory (aka NVRAM).  The first few locations of this memory were used by the clock chip to communicate the time and alarm time.  BIOSes started to use the remaining locations to store settings instead of using DIP switches.

The original IBM PCs were made up of many discrete standalone chips that performed various functions, like the PIC (8259), DMA (8237), UART (8250), the aforementioned clock chip, and others.  Eventually PC clone manufacturers consolidated all this hardware, including the clock chip, into a single *chipset* consisting of just one or two big chips, which also started to include things like a VGA adapter, USB controllers, etc.

So there is no longer a separate CMOS/clock chip and hasn't been for a long time.  The function is emulated by the chipset or Super I/O chip on the motherboard.

Also, these days the NVRAM where settings are stored are not likely not battery backed but some type of flash memory (the BIOS doesn't care as long as the chipset responds like the old CMOS clock/NVRAM) - meaning on many if not all modern systems only the clock is reset if you remove the battery.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, back in the days the clock contained 64 bytes of memory, but that memory is now seperated to some type of flash memory. The CMOS battery still powers the clock, so if the battery is reset, the clock is reset aswell. Is that correct?

Comment: is CMOS a type of memory (just like NVRAM or DRAM) or does it only refer to the 64 bytes inside the clock or Super I/O chip?

Comment: [cmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) is a 'process' of making chips - its a specific design, and many of the *other* chips you'd find in a computer or other devices may be cmos based. However *traditionally* the storage for bios/firmware settings used [cmos based sram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory) to store settings. Modern systems use flash or eeprom, and your 'cmos' battery is really a RTC battery.

Comment: CMOS just refers to the 64 (I think later versions had 128) bytes in the clock chip.  No other memory is called CMOS memory.  Why "CMOS" stuck for the name of this specific memory when it's a chip making process as @Journeyman Geek says is beyond me.

Comment: Tradition is wierd. That's why we have a *cmos* battery ;)

Comment: @LawrenceC If CMOS is a way to design ICs and thus memory, then why wouldn't we be able to create more CMOS memory besides those 64 or 128 bytes? Is it just a naming convention, where we only call those 64 bytes the CMOS memory, even though there's other memory that's also CMOS?

Comment: Pretty much just a naming convention.  I meant no other memory in a PC is called CMOS memory.